# Laravel lumen install Mail from composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, lumen

I'm trying to install Mail client on Lumen, but I get the following error:

```
mahdi@HP-EliteBook:/var/www/lumen$ composer require illuminate/mail
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.2.0, v5.1.25].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.2.0, v5.1.25].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.2.0, v5.1.25].
    - illuminate/mail v5.2.0 requires illuminate/support 5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.2.0].
    - Installation request for illuminate/mail 5.2 -> satisfiable by illuminate/mail[v5.2.0].
    - Installation request for illuminate/support == 5.1.25.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.25].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How do I install `Mail` on this micro-framework?

Answer (score 4):

Laravel and all the illuminate components were recently updated to 5.2.* (12/21/2015). Lumen, however, has not been updated and still needs the 5.1.* components.

Since you didn't specify the version of illuminate/mail to install, it tried to install the latest version (5.2). You need to require the 5.1 version instead:

```
composer require illuminate/mail:5.1.*
```